# How can I replace a certain part of array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Just need a little help here about arrays. Because I am trying to create a code that when you click it it will replace a certain array values.

In the base array suppose that we have this array:

```
Array(
   [0] => Array(
      [id] => 1,
      [name] => xyz
   ),
   [1] => Array(
      [id] => 4,
      [name] => fsa
   ),
)
```

And in my new array I have something like this

```
Array(
   [id] => 4,
   [name] => pop
)
```

I have a validation like this: In the base array I put this array in $base_array and in my new array I have $update_array

```
$get_updated_array_id = $update_array[id];

for($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($base_array); $x++){

    $target = $base_array[$x]['id'];

    if($get_updated_array_id == $target){

        //should be replace the array value ID '4'

    }

}
```

So the final result should be:

```
 Array(
       [0] => Array(
          [id] => 1,
          [name] => xyz
       ),
       [1] => Array(
          [id] => 4,
          [name] => pop
       ),
    )
```

Any idea how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: [array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: When you say "click" wouldn't you mean javascript??

Comment: Hmm no.. It should be in PHP

Comment: You can use array_map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('id' => 2,'name' => 'T'),
    array('id' => 4,'name' => 'S')
);

$replace = array('id' => 4,'name' => 'New name');

foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    if($value['id'] == $replace['id'] ) {
        $value = $replace;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Hello sir in the if statement the variable $value is it the base array?

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array = array(
   [id] => 4,
   [name] => pop
);


$get_updated_array_id = $update_array[id];

for($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($base_array); $x++){
    $target = $base_array[$x]['id'];
    if($get_updated_array_id == $target){
        $base_array[$x] = $new_array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//PHP >= 5.3

array_walk($base_array, function (& $target) use ($update_array) {
    if ($target['id'] == $update_array['id']) {
        $target = $update_array;
    }
});
```